# при нагрузке на бота вылетает ошибка Error while reading SET_OPTION's response packet

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

пишу long poll бота для вк на php. на каком-то этапе решил попробовать его под небольшой нагрузкой и через некоторое время получил такую вот ошибку:

```
PHP Warning:  mysqli::multi_query(): MySQL server has gone away in /home/meow/sites/mysqli.php on line 56

Warning: mysqli::multi_query(): MySQL server has gone away in /home/meow/sites/mysqli.php on line 56
PHP Warning:  mysqli::multi_query(): Error while reading SET_OPTION's response packet. PID=29896 in /home/meow/sites/mysqli.php on line 56

Warning: mysqli::multi_query(): Error while reading SET_OPTION's response packet. PID=29896 in /home/meow/sites/mysqli.php on line 56
PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/meow/sites/long.php on line 348

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/meow/sites/long.php on line 348

PHP Warning:  mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused in /home/meow/sites/mysqli.php on line 13

Warning: mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused in /home/meow/sites/mysqli.php on line 13
MYSQLI ERROR 2002: Connection refusedPHP Warning:  mysqli::close(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in /home/meow/sites/mysqli.php on line 20

Warning: mysqli::close(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in /home/meow/sites/mysqli.php on line 20
```

в начале каждого цикла скрипт подключается к бд, делает 1-3 запроса для чтения, потом для записи (где-то 5-7 запросов под нагрузкой) и потом отключается от бд. все запросы делаются через multi_query.

когда нагрузки нет, всё нормально работает.

в my.cnf:

```
max_allowed_packet = 256M
wait_timeout = 600
```

Comment: вы бы хоть скрипт прицепили, ничего не видно же

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Что может быть:

1) падает майскл сервер - тогда смотрите логи майскл, что не так.

2) теряется коннект - например скрипт очень долго работает и от него нет запросов, и майскл думает что скрипт закончил работу и на своей стороне закрывает соединение. Используйте mysqli::ping для этого случая.